Target Error, target is not supported
I get this error
error: target is not supported, for more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets
   --> src/lib.rs:267:9
    |
267 | /         compile_error!("\
268 | |             target is not supported, for more information see: \
269 | |             https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets\
270 | |         ");
    | |__________^

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
   --> src/lib.rs:291:5
    |
291 |     imp::getrandom_inner(dest)
    |     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `getrandom` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

but my target is supported by getrandom
mac@Kenzie stablefun % rustc -vV   
rustc 1.79.0 (129f3b996 2024-06-10)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 129f3b9964af4d4a709d1383930ade12dfe7c081
commit-date: 2024-06-10
host: x86_64-apple-darwin
release: 1.79.0
LLVM version: 18.1.7

and here is my cargo.toml
[package]
name = "stablefun"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "stablefun"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build", "anchor-spl/idl-build"]

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.30.1", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = "0.30.1"
stablebond-sdk = "2.0.0"
solana-rpc-client = "^1.18"

I dont know what to do.

It seems that you might be trying to compile your anchor program with the getrandom crate which isn't supported on Solana
read more about these limitations on the dos https://solana.com/docs/programs/limitations#rust-libraries
Make sure you are also using the latest solana tool suite to build your project and check out similar asked questions

Rust 'target is not supported' error when solana-program version at or above 1.10
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556765/anchor-build-error-got-target-is-not-supported

